# How to solve the error into IE 7 and 8 about creating dynamic file input fields?

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have a problem with Internet Explorer 7 and 8 when I try to upload multiple files by dynamic input fields. With dynamic, I mean that the user can click an "Add" button which runs some JavaScript to create a new file input field. So they end up like as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="uploads[0]"/>
<input type="file" name="uploads[1]"/>
<input type="file" name="uploads[2]"/>
```

It works fine with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer 9, but in Internet Explorer 7 and 8, I get a conversion error in Struts2 in the server side. My method is expecting a list of files, but I receive a single string with the path of the file.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that your JavaScript code which creates the form elements breaks in IE6/7/8, this can only mean that you're (indirectly) using `document.cloneNode()` to create a new input element. You shouldn't do that. Due to a bug, IE6/7/8 won't allow you to change the `name` attribute, it will instead remain the same as the original source element.

You should instead use `document.createElement()` to create brand new elements. This has in turn also a IE6/7 (not 8!) specific bug. You cannot set the `name` attribute by `setAttribute()`, instead you need to specify it directly in `createElement()` function like so.

```
document.createElement('<input name="uploads[' + index + ']">');
```

#### See also:

- [can't clone a form element in IE using .cloneNode](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/03/bug-199-cant-clone-form-element-in-ie.html)
- [createElement is broken in IE](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/10/bug-235-createelement-is-broken-in-ie.html)

Comment: I've tryed something like this... I've used the html generated by struts when i use that <s:file tag... But also not worked... The problem is that i get into Struts Action into setFileList(List<File> files) with the files... Till here its ok, but after that, i get some problem of interceptor which i dont know...

Comment: We can't do much without seeing your JS code. By the way, I'm not sure about your native language, but in English, sentences end with one period, not three.